# Problems solving strategies of experts in simple DC-circuit problems

Tags: dc, education, reference

There are many papers which study how students in high school and college think, when solving elementary DC-circuit problems. However I don't know any resources where the reasoning of experts is described in detail when solving such problems.

I am only interested in qualitative (circuits with batteries and light bulbs)- problems.

Consider for example the following question about the circuit below:

*How does the brightness of the bulbs \$\mathrm{L}_1\dots \mathrm{L}_3\$ change when the switch is closed?*

[image: Bulbs]

My first question is, if there are any resources where the qualitative reasoning of experts in solving problems like this, is documented in detail.

My second question is, how you as an expert would proceed in detail to solve  the example problem above.

Answer (score 3):

Any beginners course in electronics covers problems like this, only they use resistors with given resistance values instead of unspecified bulbs.

Suppose the power supply is 12V and each of the resistors is 2\$\Omega\$. In the case of the open switch L3 doesn't count and we have L1 and L2 in series, that's 4\$\Omega\$ in total. You can calculate the current: 12V/4\$\Omega\$ = 3A, and the power in each resistor: (3A)\$^2\$ \$\times\$ 2\$\Omega\$ = 18W.

If you close the switch L2 and L3 are in parallel, so their combined resistance is 2\$\Omega\$/2 = 1\$\Omega\$. That is series with L1 is 3\$\Omega\$ in total. Then the current is 12V/3\$\Omega\$ = 4A. That's the current through L1. L2 and L3 each see half of that: 2A.
Power in L1 is now (4A)\$^2\$ \$\times\$ 2\$\Omega\$ = 32W, and the power in L2 and L3 (2A)\$^2\$ \$\times\$ 2\$\Omega\$ = 8W.

So when the switch is closed L1 will light brighter, and L2 dimmer.

**edit**
I seem to have missed the word "qualitatively" in your question, so I'll give you another answer.

If the switch is closed the total resistance decreases due to L3 which becomes parallel to L2. So That means more current and L1 will light brighter. For L2 it's not so obvious: the total current has increased, but only half of that goes through L2. So you'll have to see whether the increase is more than double the original value. It isn't, because that would only be true if L2 was shorted. So L2 will light dimmer.

I've never seen a resource where this reasoning is explained. Logical thinking seems to be the key, maybe a course in logic (formal systems) would help. In a formal system you describe the rules of the game, like "the resistance of two lamps in parallel is half the resistance of one lamp" and "the same voltage over a lower resistance causes a higher current". From this set of rules you deduce additional, dependent rules which bring you closer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks. So would you say, that in this problem you would just replace the bulbs by resistors which obeys ohms law and calculate it as described above. So the simplification you made is to neglect the nonlinear current voltage characteristics of the light bulbs.

Comment: Yes. I have to ignore the PTC characteristics of the bulbs because the problem as stated gives us no data about it.

Comment: As a side note: When I was in high school problems like this with resistors instead of light bulbs where standard problems in physics. However today many physics educators say that it is better to treat circuits with bulbs first and solve such problems using qualitative thinking only without doing any calculations.

Comment: I think the only thing one needs to know about the current voltage characteristics, to solve this problem, is that it is monotonically increasing (higher voltage \$\iff\$ higher current) through the bulb.

Answer (score -1):

The qualitative analisys is simple.  L1 gets brighter when the switch is closed because the load in series with L1 is now L2//L3 instead of just L2.

That was my second thought process when looking at your circuit.  The first was *what are those X things?*.  The third was *why can't those #$$&*#^% use the right symbols so that the circuit is obvious at first glance!!?*

Comment: I thought this is pretty common as a symbol for a lamp. What should it be according to you?

Comment: It looks like a multiplier to me (for use in a system block diagram, not a schematic). Is using it for a lamp a European thing?

Comment: @ThePhoton At least in germany this is the usual symbol for light bulbs

Comment: My European reaction: ah, at last someone who uses the correct symbol for lamps :)

Comment: Haha, That pond between us changes a lot of things. Olin is till pretty sure you are wrong though @stevenvh. :)~   That is the symbol I use for a multiplier. I use them often in RF, nowhere else. I did manage to figure out they were lamps though from context and identifier.

Comment: @Kortuk - Yes, it's probably a European thing. I've always seen it used in electricity wiring diagrams (where there's little chance of confusing it with an HF mixer). Here it's obviously an electricity wiring diagram. Still, I haven't heard yet what the right symbol should be. And by the way, Olin is getting grumpier and grumpier, he's getting old :-)